# Some Python scripts CMD windows closes immediately

Tags: python, cmd, pycharm, python-import

Some of my python (3.6) scripts will close immediately when run. Others, however, do not. The script in question will copy a selected text and look up the word on dictionary.com. When I run the script from Pycharm, it works as intended. However, when I run it from the search bar or double-click the file from within the folder, it immediately closes. I have tried using `input("something")` and `time.sleep(1)` but with no luck. I also have success with opening a command window and typing `python dictionary.py` and enter.

This is what the body looks like:

```
import pyperclip
import keyboard
import pyautogui
import time


def lookup():
    prev = pyperclip.paste()
    time.sleep(.1)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')
    time.sleep(.1)
    word = pyperclip.paste()
    url = f"https://www.dictionary.com/browse/{word}?s=t"
    webbrowser.open(url)
    pyperclip.copy(prev)


def switch_back():
    pyautogui.keyDown('ctrl')
    pyautogui.press("w")
    pyautogui.keyUp('ctrl')
    pyautogui.keyDown('alt')
    pyautogui.press('tab')
    pyautogui.keyUp('alt')


print("Welcome to dictionary lookup!")
print("Press F2 to lookup a word on www.dictionary.com")
word = ""
keyboard.add_hotkey('f2', lookup)
keyboard.add_hotkey('f1', switch_back)
while word is not "stop":
    pass
```

Some of my other scripts that ask for input will not close immediately. The one I tried does not use any imports, so I'm theorizing this might have something to do with it. The reason I want this is that I want to be able to press windows button, type name of script and press enter. Rather than to find the folder, open a command window and type the whole thing out.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem has been resolved. A time ago I tried installing a newer version of python (3.8). I have not been using this version (because I could not figure out how to change the python interpreter in Pycharm). I tried uninstalling it, and it seems to be working now.

Comment: Interpreter could be changed in `File - Settings - Project - Project Interpreter`, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html